# HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.util.Map'

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I'm using the bean validation feature using hibernate-validator

Validator Logic

```
 public enum ValidatorFactory {
    SINGLE_INSTANCE {

  javax.validation.ValidatorFactory avf =   Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();

  @Override
  public Validator getValidator() {
     return avf.getValidator();
  }

  };

  public abstract Validator getValidator();
}
```

I'm calling validator.validate(obj) on a object which has an optional field like below

```
@UnwrapValidatedValue
@Valid
@Size(min = 1, max = 9)
private Optional<Map<Integer, AreaType>> field;
```

Error
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.util.Map'.

Answer (score 0):

According to JPA documentation:

> The size of the field or property is evaluated and must match the
>   specified boundaries. If the field or property is a String, the size
>   of the string is evaluated. If the field or property is a Collection,
>   the size of the Collection is evaluated. If the field or property is a
>   Map, the size of the Map is evaluated. If the field or property is an
>   array, the size of the array is evaluated. Use one of the optional max
>   or min elements to specify the boundaries.

With that being said you can't put @Size on Optional type, but only on String, Collections and Arrays.

Try to remove the Optional type, like this:

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 9)
private Map<Integer, AreaType> field;
```